# PHP smbclient.php error

Tags: php, share, samba, smb

Hi so I'm using the smbclient.php file from [here](http://www.smorgasbork.com/2008/07/23/accessing-smb-servers-with-php/).

When I try to run a command however it fails to run.
Upon looking at `get_last_cmd_stderr` it seems to be returning an error of `'smbclient' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. Does anyone know a solution to this as I really would like to be able to fetch file from an SMB share via PHP?

Comment: You have a testing server I can try this smbclient out on? Kind of hard to test this without have a server setup

Comment: After googling a load it seems I need smbclient.exe which I can't find anywhere... http://dev.mattcowley.co.uk/share.php is where I'm testing.

Comment: @ChadFisher 01.staging.unreal-designs.co.uk/theatre Connect as a guest.